# VS2012 Javascript Debugging Won't Work

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging, javascript-debugger

For the last 2 days I have had a right pigs ear of a problem that I just have not been able to get past.

Any time I try to debug an Windows 8 store JavaScript app using VS2012 on my laptop I get the following error:

```
>Unable to start debugging 'C:\Windows\system32\wwahost.exe'.
>
>Microsoft Visual Studio Debugging Monitor (MSCVMON.EXE) failed to
>start. If this problem persists, please repair your Visual Studio
>installation vis 'Add or Remove Programs' in control panel.
```

This happens when I try to debug locally and in simulator.

This only happens for javascript projects, all other types of projects work fine.

So far the steps I have taken are:

1. repaired installation
2. installed update 1
3. Added all application packages to program files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug on security tab.
4. uninstalled and re-installed

Nothing has worked.

Interestingly this error is about remote debugging which I am not trying to do, I didn't have remote debugging installed for 2012 but it was installed on my system for VS2008.

I installed it for VS2012 and opened the monitor while I tried to debug and nothing showed in the log.

I did an install using same VS2012 DVD on a fresh win8 desktop installation and it has no issues it all works fine although it did ask me on first run to set the permissions (I cant remember if it did this on my laptop).

I think the problem came when installing on my laptop it asked me if I wanted to import setting from previous versions of Visual Studio and I said yes.

I have done constant internet searching on this topic for last 2 days and some people are saying the problem is caused by VS2012 trying to open some VS2008 files but how to fix this is not clear.

When I uninstalled VS2012 and re-installed it didn't ask me if I wanted to import settings so I think I didn't fully un-install it (it still had a list of my recently accessed projects after the re-install).

Sorry for the long post but this has driven me crazy and I just cannot think of what to try next.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: spent today erasing every trace of every version of VS I could find from system.  Re-installed and got same error.  I had idea it might be conflicting app, i uninstalled skype as it was listening on port 80 and stopped IIS service but still get same error

Comment: I admitted defeat! Couldnt find the file/reg entry that was causing the problem so I formatted the laptop and it works fine now I have re-installed.